# ADFS Service-Communications Certificate Issue

Tags: adfs

I am trying to write a script to automation the replacement of the Service-Communications ADFS certficate. Server version is Windows 2016 Core. I am running this command as a service account that has admin permissions on the ADFS server:
`Set-AdfsCertificate -Thumbprint $thumbprint -CertificateType Service-Communications`

I get this error:

```
Set-AdfsCertificate : The specified directory service attribute or value does not exist.
At line:1 char:1

+ Set-AdfsCertificate -Thumbprint $thumbprint...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Set-AdfsCertificate], COMException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : The specified directory service attribute or value does not exist.
  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

,Microsoft.IdentityServer.Management.Commands.SetCertificateCommand
```

When I run the comand as a domain admin it works but I can't figure out what permissions are missing. Any help would be appreciated.

I haven't find any commands or articles that help me figure out what permissions are needed.

Comment: It is related to an automation script I am working on.